# Not able to see all the Contacts on Salesforce UI and getting more using REST API

Tags: visualforce

When I fetch Contact data from the Salesforce using REST API I am getting total 25 Contacts and when I check on Salesforce UI there is around 7 contact is there.

What is the reason behind this and How can I see All Cotact there ?

I know there is a filter to see i.e. Recent Contact etc.. but currently there is not All Contact filter on dropdown as well.

Below is json returned by CURL:

```
{
  "totalSize" : 25,
  "done" : true,
  "records" : [ {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "Contact",
      "url" : "/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Contact/0032v00002j1rAlAAI"
    },
    "Name" : "Rose Gonzalez"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "Contact",
      "url" : "/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Contact/0032v00002j1rAmAAI"
    },
    "Name" : "Sean Forbes"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "Contact",
      "url" : "/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Contact/0032v00002j1rAnAAI"
    },
    "Name" : "Jack Rogers"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "Contact",
      "url" : "/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Contact/0032v00002j1rAoAAI"
    },
    "Name" : "Pat Stumuller"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "Contact",
      "url" : "/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Contact/0032v00002j1rApAAI"
    },
    "Name" : "Andy Young"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "Contact",
      "url" : "/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Contact/0032v00002j1rAqAAI"
    },
    "Name" : "Tim Barr"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "Contact",
      "url" : "/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Contact/0032v00002j1rArAAI"
    },
    "Name" : "John Bond"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "Contact",
      "url" : "/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Contact/0032v00002j1rAsAAI"
    },
    "Name" : "Stella Pavlova"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "Contact",
      "url" : "/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Contact/0032v00002j1rAtAAI"
    },
    "Name" : "Lauren Boyle"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "Contact",
      "url" : "/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Contact/0032v00002j1rAuAAI"
    },
    "Name" : "Babara Levy"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "Contact",
      "url" : "/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Contact/0032v00002j1rAzAAI"
    },
    "Name" : "Tom Ripley"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "Contact",
      "url" : "/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Contact/0032v00002j1rB0AAI"
    },
    "Name" : "Liz D'Cruz"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "Contact",
      "url" : "/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Contact/0032v00002j1rB1AAI"
    },
    "Name" : "Edna Frank"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "Contact",
      "url" : "/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Contact/0032v00002j1rB2AAI"
    },
    "Name" : "Avi Green"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "Contact",
      "url" : "/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Contact/0032v00002j1rB3AAI"
    },
    "Name" : "Siddartha Nedaerk"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "Contact",
      "url" : "/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Contact/0032v00002j1rB4AAI"
    },
    "Name" : "Jake Llorrac"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "Contact",
      "url" : "/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Contact/0032v00002j1rAvAAI"
    },
    "Name" : "Josh Davis"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "Contact",
      "url" : "/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Contact/0032v00002j1rAwAAI"
    },
    "Name" : "Jane Grey"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "Contact",
      "url" : "/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Contact/0032v00002j1rAxAAI"
    },
    "Name" : "Arthur Song"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "Contact",
      "url" : "/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Contact/0032v00002j1rAyAAI"
    },
    "Name" : "Ashley James"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "Contact",
      "url" : "/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Contact/0032v00002kKb48AAC"
    },
    "Name" : "Sagar Virpara"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "Contact",
      "url" : "/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Contact/0032v00002jEXjJAAW"
    },
    "Name" : "Danny Patel"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "Contact",
      "url" : "/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Contact/0032v00002kHLIzAAO"
    },
    "Name" : "First Name Test Last Name Test"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "Contact",
      "url" : "/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Contact/0032v00002l92D9AAI"
    },
    "Name" : "Sandra Eberhard"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "Contact",
      "url" : "/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Contact/0032v00002l8aAZAAY"
    },
    "Name" : "Brenda Mcclure"
  } ]
}
```

It is saying total size is 25.

Below is screenshot from of the UI.

[image]

Comment: If you are invoking the REST API with a different user compared with what you access the UI with, this is very likely a difference in the sharing rules for the users. If you are using the same account then try viewing all the contacts rather than using a filter.

Comment: I am not using any filter and I want to see all the contacts and in the View dropdown there is no option to view all the contacts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on `Create new view` besides the view above table. You can create your own view like below.

[image]

There is no need to fill **Filter By Additional Fields**